# AES key and block size

Tags: aes, keys

I am trying to understand $AES$ and I wondered what happens in the case of a $128$ bit block size and a $256$ bit key.
All documents I read about $AES$ told me the key expansions algorithm for $128$ bit keys and $128$ bit blocks.
But I have a $256$ bit key ($8$ words) and $128$ bit block ($4$ words) and I am not sure how the key expansion works now.
Should I expand it how usual but instead beginning in the second round beginning in the third round?
Like this graphic shows:
[image]

Comment: Sorry it was a typo...

Comment: The answer to your question should be in [FIPS 197](https://www.google.de/url?q=http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi3xLLaucrKAhXFGA8KHUFkDxsQFggNMAA&usg=AFQjCNGESTAngKHqFpQo1SPkq7vt3tBKrw)

Comment: Then that's well specified in the standard document FIPS-197 of NIST, where the processing of the AES scheme is nicely described with pseudo-codes. For a concrete implementation in Python that closely follows that, see: http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7385224/1/

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Could you turn that into an answer? "Read the standard" is not much of an answer in itself, but maybe you can quote the pseudo code? Otherwise I think the question has to be closed.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: P.20 of FIPS-197 has "Figure 11 Pseudo Code for Key Expansion" and also notes that  its "Appendix A presents examples of Key Expansion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as SEJPM and Mok-Kong Shen pointed out, it's described in [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), but let's explain it in details:

Here's the Key Expansion algorithm pseudo-code from [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf):

[image]

Where

- $Nk$ is the number of $32$-bit words that composed the key
- $Nr$ is the number of rounds
- $Nb$ is the number of columns in the state block (which is always $4$).
- $word$ is a $32$-bit word (can be seen as an array of $4$ bytes).
- $w$ denotes a $4$-byte word array where the number of elements is equal to $Nr + 1$ (because AES uses a different key at each round)

For a $256$-bit key, we have $Nk = 8$ and $Nr = 14$ according to [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf).

When you are asking

> Should I expand it how usual but instead beginning in the second
>   round beginning in the third round?

Don't you mean the *fourth round*? Let me explain.

As you can see with the above pseudo-code, the first loop just copy the secret key at the beginning of the array $w$. Then, we get into the second loop to compute rounds key which are derived from the given one.

So for a $128$-bit key, you start to derive round keys as soon as $i=4$ but only when $i=8$ for a $256$-bit key (because the key is longer).

Also, as mentionned in [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), note that the routine isn't the same regarding to the key length (which is $Nk$) because there are arithmetic conditions between $i$ and $Nk$ to get into different branches of the algorithm.
For example, only $256$-bit keys will satisfy the condition **else if (Nk  >6 and i mod Nk = 4)**.

Hope it's more clear now.